# Q: GMSPlaceField results to an invalid instance?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsplace

I've noticed that if I add another field of [GMSPlaceField](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/group___place_field#ga42b0c43f73f65190674d38557b88a7b6) to my request like the one demonstrated here: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration#fetch_a_place_photo

and say make the fields like so:

```
let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.photos.rawValue))!
```

fields results to an invalid instance of GMSPlaceField:

```
GMSPlaceField   <invalid>
```

hence the request fails

Answer (score 0):

It turns out GMSPlaceField is returning the proper fields, Xcode debugger says invalid, but it is valid.